# How to solve the google map multiple times included Issue while using Auto-Loading feature

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autoload

I am in need of clarification about the issue occurred in loading Google maps api.

"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

This is occurred while I'm trying to auto load the API.

The following is the code were used. Let me know where it went wrong.

Thanks in advance....!!!

### index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapSrc.js"></script>
<script>
  function callSrc()
  {
     initMap();
  }
</script>
```

### mapSrc.js:

```
function initMap()
{
    loadAPI(); 
}

function loadAPI()
{

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules"[{"name":"maps","version":"3.exp","other_params":"sensor=false"}]}&callback=loadAPI2';    
    script.type = "text/javascript";    
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function loadAPI2()
{       
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=loadAPI3";
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);      
}

function loadAPI3() {

    google.load('visualization', '1', {
       'packages': ['table'],
       'callback':'loaded'
    });
 }

function loaded()
{
    console.log("Google map successfully loaded...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`loadAPI` and `loadAPI2` both load the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  You should only do one of those.

You need the jsapi, remove the other. Although if you read the documentation on the [autoloading](https://developers.google.com/loader/#auto-loading), you should be able to do it all in a single operation.

[Note that the `sensor` parameter is no longer required](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried by removing one of these but it is throwing error as Type Error: google.load() is not a function...

Comment: Then you removed the wrong one. You need the jsapi, remove the other.  Although if you read the documentation on the [autoloading](https://developers.google.com/loader/#auto-loading), you should be able to do it all in a single operation.

Comment: I just tried other option also but it is useless. After removing maps.googleapis.com it is throwing error as TypeError: google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor. 
Here LatLng is used in other function in same JS file.